# "program" Equivalent in Arabic

Tags: english, etymology, comparative-linguistics, arabic

Program and programming language don't have a known translation in Arabic. برمجة and برنامج are used, even though they aren't Arabic.
Is there a native word that can be used instead?

Comment: This is a legitimate linguistic question about Arabic borrowings from Greek and Persian. I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but presumably it's because if the word is used by native Arabic speakers when speaking and writing about programming in Arabic, it _is_ an Arabic word. Saying they "aren't Arabic" implies some unspecified and probably unjustifiable rule about what actually "is Arabic". Mohammed used plenty of words that had ultimately been borrowed from Aramaic and other languages (or constructed from such borrowings), and surely nobody would say he wasn't speaking and writing real Arabic as a result?

Comment: I didn't know the origin of the word. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Program" in English originally meant a structured list of things to happen (and it came from French from Latin from Greek for "edict" but that's not relevant). A computer program is a list of things for a computer to do, so the word was borrowed for that.

The common Arabic word for a structured list of things to happen is, to my knowledge, بَرْنَامَج *barnāmaj*. This was borrowed from Persian somewhere around 1500 years ago; while it might not appear in the Qur'an, it's been in Arabic longer than "program" has been in English. This then got verbed in Arabic just like "programming" did in English.

If you're looking for a pure Arabic form, you could potentially use something like جدول أعمال "itemized list of actions". But this would sound strange, like calling a computer program a "computer agenda" in English. I'd recommend sticking to the Persian words.

Comment: How to use بَرْنَامَج  to correctly derive  the equivalent to "programming" and "programming language"?
برمجة seems derived from English not Arabic, isn't it?

Comment: @SherifAhmad. barjama برجمة is to barnāmaj as falsafa فلسفة is to faylasūf. English has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @SherifAhmad Exactly what fdb said. Compare Modern Persian _barnâme_. There's no English influence here, except in the decision to use the word for "agenda" for a computer program.

Answer (score 1):

barnāmaj is a loan word from (Middle) Persian; barmaja is a remodeling of the same word according to an Arabic pattern. Although of foreign origin, these are long established Arabic words.